# page control in xcode 4.0.2

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uipagecontrol

I have a `PageControl` in a view and I implement it and its work good but not shown in `view`, there is no `PageControl` in `view`.
I can swipe between pages but its not appear for user.

What can be the reason ?

```
//  scrollView.frame.size.height
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [self.viewControllers count],280 );  scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    pageControl.numberOfPages = [self.viewControllers count];
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;

[self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the following to update the pageControl after the scrollview scrolled:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    pageControl.currentPage = scrollview.contentOffset.x / scrollview.frame.size.width;
}
```

Update:
Header file should be:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
```

Comment: i add this method but still not visible in simulator i cant saw it when i run the app

Comment: is the whole pageControl not visible? How did you create it? With IB?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;

Comment: I have updated my answer. But what 'works'? And on what view did you add the pageControl? And how did you add the scrollview?

Comment: all pages i can saw it and move between them by swipe in finger but the user didnt know there is a pages if the page control dosnt appear in the bottom of view. i add the page view in view didload method, and the scroll view in the same way like i add the page control

Comment: How did you add the pageControl? Is it in front of the scrollview?

Comment: i have on the view scrollview and page control and page control on view not on the scroll

Comment: But why is it not showing? Try removing it, create a new pageControl, don't add any outlets or anything. That should definitely show up

Comment: thank you for your help i solved it. the problem was the page control is back tabbar so am change the hight of scroll make it smaller  and change the location of the page control its show up

Comment: can you help me in other problem? im working on radio ios app and when i test it on real device its working and works in background mode but while its running the iphone does not come to sleep mode its still on always but i know after period of time the device should locked but why when my app is run the iphone does not locked? do you have an idea???

Comment: So the device is not locking while your radio app is playing in the background?

Comment: What is the phone lock settings? If you go to 'Settings' -> 'General' -> 'Auto-lock' ?

Comment: after 1 minutes its locked

Comment: and its never locked when i open my radio app

Comment: And why would you like to have the phone being locked?

Comment: because this is the default on iphone i have many app and radio app when its running the iphone locked thats the normal but my app make the iphone up normal  i think thats and this will hurt the battery